# The left-hand side of a 'for...in' statement cannot use a type annotation

Tags: typescript, types

How can I fix the error `The left-hand side of a 'for...in' statement cannot use a type annotation.`? The code in question that is not compiling is a simple for...in loop:

```
const roles = ['a', 'b', 'c'] as const
type Roles = typeof roles[number] // 'a' | 'b' | 'c'

const roles = {
  'a': '...',
  'b': '...',
  'c': '...',
}

for (const role: Roles in roles) {
  const isRole = roles.includes(roles)
}
```

I understand that is not possible to type the `role` constant, but if I don't do it the `const isRole = roles.includes(roles)` is not going to be valid: `Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '"a" | "b" | "c"'.`

Comment: Here's a [guess](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBATiANgUwjAvDA2gIgIY4A0MOARkScDgLox5qiRQDcAsAFBQCeADsjACUkqDDG58QAM3jCIWMAFcAtqWRxqzGAHotMAOR49MAD77SR03uB6OHRtBkoAsnh6iA3hxh0AXCQB0gUReMKR+OIH+wezewOGROBwAvmzsHDowABZQUDwQPjoA5gCWUJkKpP6gSlpKxcAIEFJQWgAqvMgAyg3FPC3FEBAKqFoAjABMAMyjACzpuggoMMB4YGAgsKowxWCSanDIACZ0aADWyFxSYh1Xi8guPMSkCrCXCsurMIcgYpkDPrZ2ChYHc-OdLtJxMhbsIHpoMgB3EBwU54BAKMDHTJqZAcSTImAACju2zAjnurgAlDBPDFluAHAMhEtMHcIP4dodkAAPADykmJwmpAEJ0JgALSjVJJDhAA), let me know if I understand your issue

Answer (score 24):

I could be wrong because I've only done this with `of` loops, but you should be able to enforce a type definition on the collection (right side) which informs the typing on the item.

For example:

```
for (role in roles as Roles[])
```

This should make each element of type `Roles`.

Comment: I believe this would work for `for ... of`, but not `for ... in`, as `in` is about keys rather than values.

Answer (score 5):

You can declare let variable in same scope and set also type of variable. Your example is below.

```
    const roles = ['a', 'b', 'c'] as const
    type Roles = typeof roles[number] // 'a' | 'b' | 'c'
    
    const roles = {
      'a': '...',
      'b': '...',
      'c': '...',
    }
    
    let role: Roles;
    
    for (role in roles) {
      const isRole = roles.includes(roles)
    }
```

Comment: This answer doesn't make any sense – `roles.includes(roles)`?

Answer (score 3):

In your case you may use for...of, instead of for...in, which is meant to be used with object collections and not object arrays.

What I do when using for...of is usually this:

```js
    const object = ["foo", "bar", "foz"];

    for (const iteratorUntyped of object) {
         // iteratorUntyped is just string type and cannot be used
         // to index object.

         const iterator = iteratorUntyped as typeof object[number];
         // Now it is the "foo" | "bar" | "foz" union, possibly
         // one of the object values.
    }
```

**UPDATE**

Assert the object, so it can be typed by its own expression.

```js
    const object = ["foo", "bar", "foz"] as const;

    for (const iterator of object) {
         // Each iterator is "foo" | "bar" | "foz".
    }
```

Comment: This helped me with a bug in rss-parser. Thank you.

Comment: The question was about typing the _keys_ in a `for ... in` loop. `for ... of` is about values.

Answer (score 1):

TSLint had [similar issue](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/743) in 2015. And solved it by disallowing type definitions inside of for loop as commented in [the fix of issue](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/commit/afdb4d1ce065475215a12273cfa20af5f5847e8d).

So we are forbidden to place a type definition there.

Comment: Such decision sounds incredibly smart...

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing issue with enum, you can utilise this helper.

```
function enumKeys<O extends object, K extends keyof O = keyof O>(
  obj: O
): K[] {
  return Object.keys(obj).filter((k) => Number.isNaN(+k)) as K[];
}
```

usage:

```
export enum Mode {
  Plain = "Plain",
  Pointer = "Pointer"
}

for (const mode of enumKeys(Mode)) {
   myFunction(Mode[mode]);
}
```

more on this here:
[iterating-typescript-enum](https://www.petermorlion.com/iterating-a-typescript-enum/)

Answer (score 0):

Not ideal, but you could pre-establish the type of the variable with a "let":

```
let role: Roles;
for (role in roles) {
  const isRole = roles.includes(roles)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Consider using `of` instead of `in`:

```
for (const role of roles) {
  const isRole = roles.includes(roles)
}
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem